# How to add method to vendor class?

Tags: php, laravel

Could you tell me guys how to add a new method to vendor class for example for: 
vendor/illuminate/html/FormBuilder.php

Whats the proper way to extend my laravel classes? I guess craeting new class somewhere in app folder?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to extend the actual Laravel packages is to create your own package that require and extends (in your case) the Illuminate FormBuilder object. First check out the official docs [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/packages).

Be aware that the Form Builder is deprecated and no longer supported in the last Laravel releases. You can use the [LaravelCollective Package](https://laravelcollective.com/) instead.

So, let's recap... To achieve your goal you should:

- Create your own package that requires the LaravelCollective component
- Extend the LaravelCollective FormBuilder adding your own methods
- Register your package into Laravel Container binding your own Service Container

Comment: Trust me, It's easier than you expect. Just follow the Laravel docs step by step